# Focus Detection using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, focus, detection

I am trying to identify which parts of a picture are in focus and which are blurred, something like this: 
[image: Focus Detection]

But HOW to do that? Any ideas on how to mesure this? I've read something about finding the high frequencies but how could it produce a picture like those?

Cheers,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any image will be the sharpest at its optimum focus. Take advantage of that - run the Sobel operator or the Laplace operator, any kind of difference(derivative) filter. Sum the results pixel by pixel, the image with the highest sum is the best focused one.

Edit:
There will be additional constraints depending on how much additional information you have, e.g. multiple samples, similarity of objects in the image, etc.

Comment: Would that be possible to use Laplace operator data to feed a foreground extractor?

Comment: I do not have experience with such extractors, hopefully someone else around could weigh in :)

Comment: For using Laplace for detecting amount of blurriness with opencv, see here:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/
They rely on this paper:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8c67/5bf5b542b98bf81dcf70bd869ab52ab8aae9.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Check out this paper for more precision over the Laplace filter. In my problem with 4K images, the Laplace filter was insufficient for detecting blurs and out-of-focus regions.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/DeepFocus

edit: Blur detection with deep learning has a number of approaches. Choose the method that best suits your needs:)